# django-displaying data the way they are entered by the user

Tags: html, database, django

I have a models.py file where i have a textfield

models.py

```
class xyz(models.Models):
    abc=models.TextField()
```

I am using html form to save the data for the *abc* field.

The problem is that if i enter the data in multiple lines in the form and try to display it, the whole matter is displayed in a single line.

So what is the error?
Is it in the models or what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The user enters a plain text, and than you are trying to show it as HTML. these are different formats.

There are a lot of possibilities, the simplest one is to let the user enter HTML and than everything will work as expected.

To do this, use some HTML editor like [tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)

Other solution is to use some [markup formatting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/markup/)